# How can I determine the return type of a functor which takes that type for a parameter?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, type-deduction, return-type-deduction

Suppose I have to following function:

```
template <typename Op, typename T> T foo(Op op) { }
```

Op is assumed to have the following method:

```
T Op::operator()(T&);
```

(this is a simple case; actually it might have more parameters but their types are known to me).

Now, I want to set a default for the `T` parameter. The problem is, in order to faux-invoke it (e.g. as in `std::result_of<Op::operator()(int&)>` I need to have the type of the parameter - which is exactly the type I'm missing.

Is it possible to determine `T` from `Op`? So that I may, for example, call:

```
foo( [](int& x){ return x++; } );
```

I'm interested in a C++11 solution; if you need a later-standard-version capability, that's also interesting (especially the explanation of why that is).

Note: If `Op` has multiple compatible operator()`'s taking references to different types, I'm ok with having to specify`T` myself, of course - but the compilation should pass when I do that.

Comment: Should `foo(Op op) { }` be `T foo(Op op) { }`?

Comment: Also, do you actually need to know `T`?  You can use `auto` return type deduction.

Comment: Since the function takes function as the argument, where does the callback's argument come from? Imho this is crucial here

Comment: What if the function object has multiple overloads with different return types?

Comment: @NathanOliver: 1. Yes. 2. Yes, because without it, I can't invoke Op. Also for other reasons not in this example.

Comment: @eerorika: I'm willing to ignore that possibility, or rather - to always specify T in that case.

Comment: @einpoklum If you need it to know how to call `op`, then why provide a default?  What meaning would that default have?

Comment: @NathanOliver: A default for T would let me call `foo()` without explicitly specifying anything.

Answer (score 4):

*If* the function object has **exactly one** signature, you can discover that signature by `decltype(&T::operator())` and infer from that:

```
template<class T> struct X : X<decltype(&T::operator())> {}; // #1
template<class T> struct X<T(T&) const> { using type = T; }; // #2
template<class C, class M> struct X<M (C::*)> : X<M> {}; // #3
// add more specializations for mutable lambdas etc. - see example

template <typename Op, typename T = typename X<Op>::type>
T foo(Op op) { /* ... */ }
```

[Example](https://godbolt.org/z/kbhNr4) (C++11).

---

This is a series of type transformations, expressed as partial template specializations. From a lambda with anonymous type `<lambda>`, we extract its function call operator type at `#1` giving a member function pointer type such as `int (<lambda>::*)(int&) const`, which matches `#3` allowing us to discard the class type giving an [abominable](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/p0172r0.html) function type `int(int&) const`, which matches `#2` allowing us to extract the argument and return type, exposed as `X::type` which is visible to the original instantiation of `X` via inheritance. Using partial specializations of the same template for different type computations is a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) trick and you might want to avoid it (and use more expressive names) in production code.

---

If on the other hand the function object has more than one signature (template parameters, default parameters, [`overloaded`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit), hand-crafted function objects, etc.) then this will not work; you will need to wait for stronger forms of reflection to enter the language.

Comment: @eerorika ah yeah, forgot to mention that you need to add a couple more specializations for generality. Thanks!

Comment: Nice... and it [doesn't break the compilation when you have multiple operator()'s](https://godbolt.org/z/rnMWzW). +1.

Comment: Can you expand some more on how this solution works exactly?

Comment: @einpoklum added an explanation

Answer (score 1):

The existence of template functions shows the question is impossible to answer in general:

```
struct post_increment
{
    template<typename T>
    T operator()(T& t) const
    {
        return t++;
    }
};

foo(post_increment{});
// or in C++14: foo([](auto& t) { return t++; });
```

The result of a function `foo` taking a mapping `T&` to `T` for some set of types `T` is itself polymorphic. In some cases, this is expressible even in C++11:

```
template<typename Op>
struct foo_result_t
{
    template<typename T>
    operator T() const
    {
        T t {};
        op(t);
        return t;
    }

    Op op;
};

template <typename Op>
foo_result_t<Op> foo(Op op)
{
     return {op};
}

int i = foo(post_increment{}); // use it with an int
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. First, you mean the question is "impossible to answer", not "impossible", right? Also, we already have an answer, albeit making a simplifying assumption.

Comment: "impossible" -> "impossible to answer" thanks. Yes, simplifying to function pointer or a function object with only one operator() (which is roughly the same) can give an answer. What I was trying to contribute with the answer was that altering the question (because there is no T to deduce in general) can also provide a working/convenient solution in some contexts, even in C++11.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution in case of exactly one signature.

Another... well... almost the same ecatmur's solution but based on a template function, to deduce the types, instead of a template class.

All you need is <s>a declared function</s> two declared functions that deduce the types (and return the same return type of the `operator()`; you can develop also another function to return, by example, `std::tuple<Args...>`, if you needs to extract the `Args...` types)

```
template <typename T, typename R, typename ... Args>
R deducer (R(T::*)(Args...) const);

template <typename T, typename R, typename ... Args>
R deducer (R(T::*)(Args...));
```

and a `using` (a little `decltype()` delirium) to extract the `R` type

```
template <typename T>
using RetType = decltype(deducer(std::declval<decltype(&T::operator())>()));
```

The following is a full C++11 example

```
#include <utility>

struct A
 {
   long operator() (int, char, short)
    { return 0l; }
 };

template <typename T, typename R, typename ... Args>
R deducer (R(T::*)(Args...) const);

template <typename T, typename R, typename ... Args>
R deducer (R(T::*)(Args...));

template <typename T>
using RetType = decltype(deducer(std::declval<decltype(&T::operator())>()));

int main ()
 {
   auto f = [](int& x) { return x++; };

   static_assert( std::is_same<RetType<A>, long>::value, "!" );
   static_assert( std::is_same<RetType<decltype(f)>, int>::value, "!" );
 }
```

If you wont to manage also `volatile` operators, you have to add other two `deducer()`

```
template <typename T, typename R, typename ... Args>
R deducer (R(T::*)(Args...) volatile const);

template <typename T, typename R, typename ... Args>
R deducer (R(T::*)(Args...) volatile);
```

Comment: I think your deducer [doesn't work for lambdas](https://godbolt.org/z/A_LU_U).

Comment: @einpoklum - yes... I ever forget the constness part... to make it working you have to declare `mutable` the lambda (or, to make it fail, you can declare `const` the `operator()` of `A`)... we need a second `deducer()` for const operators... some minutes...

Comment: @einpoklum - Corrected. Well... partially corrected: if you want also manage `volatile` methods (but are useful `volatile` methods?) you have to add other two `deducer()`: one for `volatile` and one for `volatile const`.